# How to add noise filter/effect on Image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart-ui

I want to create a mesh gradient with blur and noise effect. I already added blur effect using ImageFilter but don't know how to add grainy noise on top of it.[image]

Comment: please add image of desired result

Comment: Already added. Above Image has slight noise on top of blur. Kindly check again.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by adding png of grainy texture, but I hope there are some better ways. I am open for further inputs.

```
  Opacity(
       opacity: 0.1,
       child: Image.asset(
      'assets/images/noise.png',
       height: double.infinity,
       width: double.infinity,
       fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
 ),
```

[image]